# Find 10 digits in a row, format them to phone number ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, string, numbers, format

I have a form that is submitted via a website which generates an email. All of the fields from the form are stored in the ASP code as one big string "strMsgInfo". I want to parse the string, find 10 digits in a row, which is the phone number field, and then format those 10 numbers as 000-000-0000 so that when the email comes up on my phone, I can click the phone number instead of having to type it in manually.

I also want to keep the rest of the string in-tact.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, use a for loop to iterate throught all characters. If the first character is a number, check if the next is one too. Go until you reach 10.

Edit:

```
for i = 0 to string.length - 1
    if checkisnumber(string[i]) then
        telnr &= string[i]
        continue = true
    else
        continue = false
    end if
    if telnr.length = 10 and continue = true then
        end for
    else
        telnr = ""
    end if
next
string = string.replace(telnr, telnr.Insert(3, "-").Insert(8, "-")
```

Note that after you insert at index 3, the second - is not located at 7 but 8, because the string is already increased in length by 1. Because Insert at index x inserts at that position, all characters starting from that position are moved up by one.

Regards,

Niru

Comment: Understood, but if I also have letters in the string before or after the if statement to check for numbers, how can i format just those 10 numbers while keeping the rest of the string in-tact?

Comment: This wouldn't work because if there are elements added to the String before the number comes along, you're replacing the entire string with just the formatted numbers, so what was in the string previously is now gone

Comment: The above code is not adding anything to the string. The code is checking through a loop the string for the first occurance of a number. Everytime a number is found, the number is stored inside telnr. If the next time the loop is run, and the next character is not a number, then bool continue is set false, because we dont have a number following a number. At the end i am replacing your string with the string itself, except that this time the found number occurance is replaced with the edited number occurance.

Comment: Last question. TelNR needs to be initialized as an integer, yes?

Comment: No, you can initialize it as a string, after all you are adding a string to a string, otherwise you have to cast the string

Comment: Just employed this, initialized telNR as a string, the code does not work, it still sends the numbers as 10 straight digits from the "phone number" location in the string array.

Comment: Nice to hear. If my answer helped you, would be glad if you marked it as the answer.